# Want to get specific values in string xml java

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns2:services xmlns:ns2="http://www.3ds.com/enovia/e6wv2"><ns2:serviceData><ns2:statusCode>200</ns2:statusCode><ns2:success>true</ns2:success><ns2:csrf name="ENO_CSRF_TOKEN" value="JYOF-K5LS-INZM-15O3-4O00-VTBJ-R28O-YY2P"/></ns2:serviceData></ns2:services>`

my string xml . in this want to get value output

Comment: What you have tried to achieve this?

Comment: @PradeepSimha I have store the XML in string and tried to retrieve but can't able to get the value.help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should use a library like SAX parser to Deserialize an input stream like XML.

But if you want to do this using no libraries maybe the method below can help:

```
private String getCsrfValue(String xml){
    String value = "";

    if(xml!= null && xml.length() > 0) {
        int csfrIndex = xml.indexOf("csrf");
        if (csfrIndex != -1) {
            String subXml = xml.substring(csfrIndex);

            int valueIndex = subXml.indexOf("value");

            if (valueIndex != -1) {
                int firstCommaIndex = -1;
                int secondCommaIndex = -1;
                boolean firstInvCommaFound = false;

                for (int i = valueIndex; i < subXml.length(); i++) {
                    if (subXml.charAt(i) == '\"') {
                        if (!firstInvCommaFound) {
                            firstCommaIndex = i;
                            firstInvCommaFound = true;
                        } else {
                            secondCommaIndex = i;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (firstCommaIndex != -1 && secondCommaIndex != -1 && secondCommaIndex < xml.length()) {
                    value = subXml.substring(firstCommaIndex + 1, secondCommaIndex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```